# Dynamic launcher with Tasker?

Tags: tasker, launcher

I'd like to use Tasker to switch my launcher: when I'm at work I need certain apps to be easily available, while when I'm home I want Nova launcher with all my apps. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit dirty solution, but gets the job done.

**Note**: Tested the solution on Android 4.2.1 having default Android launcher and [Smart Launcher Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ginlemon.flowerpro).

#### Requirements:

- Device should be rooted

---

I'm assuming:

- Your timing for work (i.e. entering and leaving the office) are more or less same for working days. Let's say the timing is **10:OO AM - 06:00 PM**, and the rest is for home or other things.
- You're using your device's default launcher and [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en).

#### Instructions for [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm):

1. Make [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en) as your default launcher by using step 2 and 3 from this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110118/96277) by [Josh Holland](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/43185/josh-holland).
2. Launch [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm).
3. Create a Profile under **Time** with parameters as:

   - **From**: `10:00`
   - **To**: `18:00`
4. Create a task with action **Code → Run Shell**, and fill these details:

   - **Command**: `pm disable com.teslacoilsw.launcher`
   - **Timeout (Seconds)**: `10`
   - Check **Use Root**, leave other things untouched and save the action
5. Under the same task create a new action **App → Launch App**. Under the **App Selection** window tap **All** (at the bottom) and choose the default launcher. Save this action with other things untouched.
6. Create another profile under **Time** with parameters:

   - **From**: `18:00`
   - **To**: `10:00`
7. Repeat step 4 with details:

   - **Command**: `pm enable com.teslacoilsw.launcher`
   - **Timeout (Seconds)**: `10`
   - Check **Use Root**, leave other things untouched and save the action
8. Repeat step 5 and choose [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en) to launch instead of default one.
9. Enable both profiles and the [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm).

You're good to go. Your default launcher will be activated for work time and [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en) will activate during home or leisure activity.

Note that you can change the timings, or the default profile as well. E.g. If you don't want to limit the answer with timings or your timings are not strict but irregular than you may try a profile like **State → Net State → Wifi Connected** → details of Wifi.

Answer (score 3):

Any solution you find *will* require root, due to Android's security limitations (3rd-party apps cannot change the default action for intents).

http://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/11swoq/how_to_use_tasker_to_swap_between_launchers/ looks promising, I'll summarise it quickly here.

Requirements:

- [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)
- [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin&hl=en)
- A second launcher installed
- Root access

  1. Install Secure Settings, grant it root access and under **Options → Root access** make sure **Package Manager** is enabled.
  2. Go to **System settings → Apps**, open the entry for your **current launcher** and press **Clear defaults**.
  3. Press the home button, select your **alternate launcher** (probably the "at work" launcher in this case) and **select the 'Always' option**.
  4. If you have **more than two launchers** installed, you must proceed with step 5. Otherwise (if you have **exactly two** launchers installed), skip to **step 13**.
  5. Open Tasker, and add a new task in the "Tasks" tab (named something like "Disable stock launcher").
  6. Add an action: **Plugin → Secure Settings**.
  7. Click the **edit button** next to 'Configuration'.
  8. Pick **'Package Manager'** under 'Root actions'.
  9. Click the **question mark (?)** in the **top-left corner** and select your stock launcher (or whichever launcher you **do not** want to use at all).
  10. Make sure the grey toggle in the middle is **set to 'Disabled'**.
  11. Press the **Save button** in the bottom-left, then the **green check** in Tasker.
  12. Press the **Test/Play button** in the bottom-right; this will disable your stock launcher (or whichever launcher you don't want to use).
  13. In Tasker, go to the profile you want to use your **alternate launcher** with (probably "At work" in this case).
  14. In the Entry task add a new action: **Plugin → Secure Settings**.
  15. Edit the plugin configuration: **Edit → Package Manager**.
  16. Select your **alternate launcher** (the "at work" launcher in this case).
  17. Set the grey toggle to **'Enable'**.
  18. Press **Save** in the bottom-left, then tick the checkmarks to commit.
  19. For the **exit task**, do the exact same, except make sure the toggle **disables** your alternate launcher rather than enables.

N.B. As always with tasks involving root access, there is a small risk of ending up without a usable launcher; as long as you follow the instructions in the [Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/11swoq/how_to_use_tasker_to_swap_between_launchers/), you should be fine.

Comment: You need to pay for that feature to work on Secure Settings app on the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

[Sloth Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slothlauncher) does exactly what you want.

Comment: Removed from the store

Answer (score 0):

[UR Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sien.ur.moodlauncher&hl=en) Is a dynamic launcher, I am using it on my own but still needs some features, I am also searching for better and better

Comment: This seems to have been removed from the play store. Yes I realize this is an old post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking, try CTX Launcher:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.cenapps.ctxlauncher

You can use Tasker to change shortcuts and widgets shown on screen.

PS: I'm the developer, it's my first app. Your feedback would be appreciated.